# akka stream CPU usage monitoring

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

We have several akka streams running in our app, and I'd like to find CPU usage by each of them. They share the same actor system.

My idea is find out how much time each `Runnable` responsible for processing island inbox spends running and treat it as CPU usage time, but it seems to be impossible to instrument `ActorSystem` to achieve this. I could, for example:

- create new `Materializer` for every graph by calling `withNamePrefix` on the base one. This will give name prefixes to all actors so I can figure out which graph they belong to
- (impossible) globally intercept `Actor.receive` to time execution and attribute it to a graph based on actor name

Our graphs are quite complex so I'd like to avoid manually instrumenting every `Flow`.

I'm new to akka/streams so I hope I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: kamon might be able to help you out: https://kamon.io/documentation/1.x/instrumentation/akka/

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil: already saw it, thanks. As I see it uses AspectJ, and I'll try doing the same to my second bullet point.

Comment: @eprst You can use Java bytecode instrumentation using agent to replace `class Actor` with your proxy to track calls to `receive`.

Comment: I guess you are looking for something that is free as in beer but Lightbend telemetry (commercial) has stream instrumentation capabilities: https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/telemetry/current//instrumentations/akka-streams/akka-streams.html